# Prove that $\sqrt {2^n-1}$ is irrational for every integer $ n>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing, perfect-powers

> Prove that $\sqrt {2^n-1}$ is irrational for every integer $ n>1$

I tried assuming it was equal to $\frac p q $.

I get $2^nq^2-q^2 = p^2 $

But I don't see where to go from there.

Comment: Related: [Show that $(2^n-1)^{1/n}$ is irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422990)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For $n\geq2$, $2^n-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$, unlike a perfect square.

Comment: To note for the questioner, the square root of non-square number is irrational.

Comment: So you are using that [$\sqrt a$ is either an integer or an irrational number](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467)

Comment: @HanulJeon I was actually just waiting for the questioner to ask if he doesn't get the hint :)

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast!

Comment: I didn't see that $2^n-1$ was congruent to 3 mod 4. I will look into why the square root of such numbers are always irrational

Comment: Prove that no perfect square can be congruent to 3 mod 4. Take any perfect square, it must be $(2n)^2$ or $(2n+1)^2$. Does it help?

Comment: I get it thanks!

Comment: Should I ask a new question to prove that $ \sqrt[n] { x^n -1 }$ is always irrational?

Comment: I think I can prove it using Fermat last theorem..

Answer (score 1):

Landon Carter's answer is direct and has the elegance of simplicity. Here is a partial answer for the case $n=2k$, an even number.
I too use the fact that if the square root is rational it has to be an integer.

So we assume $2^{2k}-1$ is a square and will get a contradiction.
That is, $(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$ is a square. The these bracketed quantities are both odd and differ by 2, hence have no common factors.

So this forces both the numbers i.e., $2^{2k}\pm1$ to be perfect squares.
AT the beginning the squares $1$ and $4$ differ by $3$, afterwards squares have to differ by more than 3.

Here we have two squares differing by 2.
Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

To continue your idea, rather than to restart and do one of the other correct answers.

$2^nq^2 - q^2 = p^2$.

Assume $p = 1$

The $2^nq^2 - q^2 = 1$.  Then $2^n - 1 = 1/q^2$ is an integer.  So $q=1$.  So $2^n - 1 = 1$.  So $2^n = 2$ so $n = 1 \not > 1$.

Assume $p \ne 1$.

Let $k$ be a prime factor of $p$.  Then either $k|q^2$ which isn't possible as we assumed (or should have assumed) $p/q$ is in lowest terms, or $k|2^n - 1$.

This is true for all prime factors so $p^2|2^n -1$.

So $q^2\frac{2^n - 1}{p^2} = 1$ and $\frac{2^n - 1}{p^2} \in \mathbb Z$ so $\frac{2^n - 1}{p^2} = 1/q^2 \in \mathbb Z$ so $q = \pm 1$ and

$2^n - 1 = p^2$.

$p$ is clearly odd so let $p = 2p' + 1$

$2^n = 4p'^2 + 4p' + 2$

$4 \not \mid 4p'^2 + 4p +2 = 2^n$ so $n < 2$.  So $n \le 1$.  So $n \not > 1$.

Answer (score -1):

It is clearly equivalent to prove that the diophantine equation $$2^n=x^2+1$$ has no integer solution for $n\gt 1$ Notice that $x$ must be odd so $x=2m+1$ hence
$$2^n=(4m^2+4m+1)+1=4m^2+4m+2\iff2^{n-1}=2m^2+2m+1$$ This is absurde.

Comment: It was obviously a lapsus taking $x=2n+1$ with the same symbol $n$ that the exponent. This maked, I hope you change your downvote because if not you are doing the worst in maths (¿what is it?)

Comment: Not sure why it should by clear or obvious that $2^n = x^2 +1$ having no rational solutions is equivalent to showing it has no integer solutions.  It is, but I don't don't see why it is "clear".  Unless you assume $x^2 = p/q$ implies $p/q$ is an integer.  Which does need to be proven at some point or another.  Probably around the same time as the student would be asked this problem.

Comment: Do you have in hand an example of $2^n−1$ rational non integer? I want to confess frankly that I wanted to write yesterday a comment like this: “Do not be a coward and justify your downvote”. But I censured myself and decided not to write it, I gave it as past history, without any bitterness, believe me, please.

Comment: Of course, I don't.  But it wouldn't be obvious to a student at this level that there can't be. " If $\sqrt{m}$ is rational then $m$ is a perfect square" is something a student needs to be but hasn't nescessarily yet proven.  Why are you talking about downvoting?  I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Anyway, what I have told you  about my censured comment is true and this is not necessarily directed to you. Regards.